# Remove HTML Tags in Javascript with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove all the html tags out of a string in Javascript.
Heres what I have... I can't figure out why its not working....any know what I am doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var regex = "/<(.|\n)*?>/";
var body = "<p>test</p>";
var result = body.replace(regex, "");
alert(result);

</script>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Try this, noting that the grammar of HTML is too complex for regular expressions to be correct 100% of the time:

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
,   body = "<p>test</p>"
,   result = body.replace(regex, "");

console.log(result);
```

If you're willing to use a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you could simply do this:

```
console.log($('<p>test</p>').text());
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the regex in a string?

 var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;

Comment: This won't work.  Specifically, it will fail on short tags: http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-9.htm#SHORTTAG

Comment: This is an old question but I'll just post this here: http://jsperf.com/regex-replace-vs-jquery-text

Comment: this might be a solution to the short tag problem: var regex = /(<([^>]*)>)/ig

Comment: Why are the parenthesis for ? you dont use any groups here

Comment: Try running this on `"<img src=bogus onerror=alert(1337)"`.  The first fails because the HTML parser doesn't require that the last tag be closed by a `>`, and the second fails because image loading starts even before a parsed DOM tree is added to the DOM, and `$('<img ...>')` invokes the HTML parser.

Comment: The regex solution will also fail if a `>` is included in an attribute value; like this `<div data="a + b > c">`

Answer (score 40):

This is an old question, but I stumbled across it and thought I'd share the method I used:

```js
var body = '<div id="anid">some <a href="link">text</a></div> and some more text';
var temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.innerHTML = body;
var sanitized = temp.textContent || temp.innerText;
```

`sanitized` will now contain: `"some text and some more text"`

Simple, no jQuery needed, and it shouldn't let you down even in more complex cases.

### Warning

This can't *safely* deal with user content, because it's vulnerable to script injections. For example, running this:

```
var body = '<img src=fake onerror=alert("dangerous")> Hello';
var temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.innerHTML = body;
var sanitized = temp.textContent || temp.innerText;
```

Leads to an alert being emitted.

Comment: I first tried this but it's subject to xss injection. If you try to sanitize `<img src=fake onerror=alert("dangerous")>` you will run the `onerror` js.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me.

```
   var regex = /(&nbsp;|<([^>]+)>)/ig
      ,   body = tt
     ,   result = body.replace(regex, "");
       alert(result);
```

Comment: +1 thanks.  this one liner woked perfect for my needs. `console.log( my_html.replace(/(&nbsp;|<([^>]+)>)/ig, "") );`

Answer (score 11):

This is a solution for HTML tag and &nbsp etc and you can remove and add conditions
to get the text without HTML and you can replace it by any.

```
convertHtmlToText(passHtmlBlock)
{
   str = str.toString();
  return str.replace(/<[^>]*(>|$)|&nbsp;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;|&gt;/g, 'ReplaceIfYouWantOtherWiseKeepItEmpty');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would add also "&#34;" -> "html_string".replace(/<[^>]*(>|$)|&nbsp;|&#34;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;|&gt;/g, ''); Cheers!

Comment: "html_string".replace(/<[^>]*(>|$)|&nbsp;|&#34;|&#39;|&zwnj;|&raquo;|&laquo;|&gt;/g, '');   --> added &#34;|&#39;

Answer (score 8):

Here is how TextAngular (WYSISYG Editor) is doing it. I also found this to be the most consistent answer, which is NO REGEX.

```
@license textAngular
Author : Austin Anderson
License : 2013 MIT
Version 1.5.16
// turn html into pure text that shows visiblity
function stripHtmlToText(html)
{
    var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    var res = tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || '';
    res.replace('\u200B', ''); // zero width space
    res = res.trim();
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my **simple** JavaScript library called FuncJS has a function called "strip_tags()" which does the task for you — without requiring you to enter any regular expressions.

For example, say that you want to remove tags from a sentence - with this function, you can do it simply like this:

```
strip_tags("This string <em>contains</em> <strong>a lot</strong> of tags!");
```

This will produce "This string contains a lot of tags!".

For a better understanding, please do read the documentation at
[GitHub FuncJS](https://github.com/sharikul/FuncJS/blob/master/README.md).

Additionally, if you'd like, please provide some feedback through the form. It would be very helpful to me!

Comment: Could you perhaps provide what `strip_tags()` does instead of just promoting your library and not explaining it? The link explains the API usage but not _what it does_.

Comment: well, found it on that website he gave, `strip_tags = function(e) {
var _hasTag, _tag_string;
if (!(e === void 0 || e === null || e === "")) {
_tag_string = e;
if (typeof _tag_string === "object") {
_tag_string = _tag_string.outerHTML;
}
_hasTag = _tag_string.match(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig);
if (_hasTag) {
return trim(_tag_string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ''));
} else {
return trim(_tag_string);
}
}
else {
throw new Error("The 'strip_tags' function expects one argument in the form of a string or object.");
}
};`

Answer (score 1):

you can use a powerful library for management String which is [undrescore.string.js](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string)

```
_('a <a href="#">link</a>').stripTags()
```

=> 'a link'

```
_('a <a href="#">link</a><script>alert("hello world!")</script>').stripTags()
```

=> 'a linkalert("hello world!")'

Don't forget to import this lib as following :

```
        <script src="underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="underscore.string.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> _.mixin(_.str.exports())</script>
```

Comment: I looked at the source, and they actually use the same regex suggested in other answer internally.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is practically a one-liner.

The function creates a [Range object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) and then creates a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment) in the Range with the string as the child content.

Then it grabs the text of the fragment, removes any "invisible"/zero-width characters, and trims it of any leading/trailing white space.

I realize this question is old, I just thought my solution was unique and wanted to share. :)

```
function getTextFromString(htmlString) {
    return document
        .createRange()
        // Creates a fragment and turns the supplied string into HTML nodes
        .createContextualFragment(htmlString)
        // Gets the text from the fragment
        .textContent
        // Removes the Zero-Width Space, Zero-Width Joiner, Zero-Width No-Break Space, Left-To-Right Mark, and Right-To-Left Mark characters
        .replace(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF\u200E\u200F]/g, '')
        // Trims off any extra space on either end of the string
        .trim();
}

var cleanString = getTextFromString('<p>Hello world! I <em>love</em> <strong>JavaScript</strong>!!!</p>');

alert(cleanString);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is example replace character html and trim space

```js
function cleanAndTrimString(inputString) {
  // Remove HTML characters using a regular expression
  const withoutHtml = inputString.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');

  // Trim multiple spaces and leading/trailing spaces
  const trimmedAndCleaned = withoutHtml.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();

  return trimmedAndCleaned;
}

// Example usage:
const input = "<p>  This is an example with <b>HTML</b>    characters.</p>";
const cleanedString = cleanAndTrimString(input);
console.log(cleanedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a proper HTML sanitizer in JS, see http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer doesn't always ensure that HTML is stripped, as it's still possible to construct an invalid HTML string through it by crafting a string like the following.

```
  "<<h1>h1>foo<<//</h1>h1/>"
```

This input will ensure that the stripping assembles a set of tags for you and will result in:

```
  "<h1>foo</h1>"
```

additionally jquery's text function will strip text not surrounded by tags.

Here's a function that uses jQuery but should be more robust against both of these cases:

```
var stripHTML = function(s) {
    var lastString;

    do {            
        s = $('<div>').html(lastString = s).text();
    } while(lastString !== s) 

    return s;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function striptag(){
var html = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
for (i=0; i < arguments.length; i++)
arguments[i].value=arguments[i].value.replace(html, "")
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>
       <form name="myform">
<textarea class="comment" title="comment" name=comment rows=4 cols=40></textarea><br>
<input type="button" value="Remove HTML Tags" onClick="striptag(this.form.comment)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with a library and are not using JQuery, the best JS library specifically for this purpose is [striptags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags.).

It is heavier than a regex (17.9kb), but if you need greater security than a regex can provide/don't care about the extra 17.6kb, then it's the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

Like others have stated, regex will not work. Take a moment to read my [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/parsing-html-regular-expressions-drew-durham) about why you cannot and should not try to parse html with regex, which is what you're doing when you're attempting to strip html from  your source string.