# How can I change handleError?

Tags: jquery

I have jquery script, which should send response to my file. If everything good, I get success, but if wrong, I should get error function, but I get `jQuery.handleError is not a function
jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status, e);`

How can I change this handleError to other function? Or what can I do?

```
jQuery.extend({

createUploadIframe: function(id, uri)
{
        //create frame
        var frameId = 'jUploadFrame' + id;
        var iframeHtml = '<iframe id="' + frameId + '" name="' + frameId + '" style="position:absolute; top:-9999px; left:-9999px"';
        if(window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            if(typeof uri== 'boolean'){
                iframeHtml += ' src="' + 'javascript:false' + '"';

            }
            else if(typeof uri== 'string'){
                iframeHtml += ' src="' + uri + '"';

            }   
        }
        iframeHtml += ' />';
        jQuery(iframeHtml).appendTo(document.body);

        return jQuery('#' + frameId).get(0);            
},
createUploadForm: function(id, fileElementId, data)
{
    //create form   
    var formId = 'jUploadForm' + id;
    var fileId = 'jUploadFile' + id;
    var form = jQuery('<form  action="" method="POST" name="' + formId + '" id="' + formId + '" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>');    
    if(data)
    {
        for(var i in data)
        {
            jQuery('<input type="hidden" name="' + i + '" value="' + data[i] + '" />').appendTo(form);
        }           
    }       
    var oldElement = jQuery('#' + fileElementId);
    var newElement = jQuery(oldElement).clone();
    jQuery(oldElement).attr('id', fileId);
    jQuery(oldElement).before(newElement);
    jQuery(oldElement).appendTo(form);



    //set attributes
    jQuery(form).css('position', 'absolute');
    jQuery(form).css('top', '-1200px');
    jQuery(form).css('left', '-1200px');
    jQuery(form).appendTo('body');      
    return form;
},

ajaxFileUpload: function(s) {
    // TODO introduce global settings, allowing the client to modify them for all requests, not only timeout        
    s = jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.ajaxSettings, s);
    var id = new Date().getTime()        
    var form = jQuery.createUploadForm(id, s.fileElementId, (typeof(s.data)=='undefined'?false:s.data));
    var io = jQuery.createUploadIframe(id, s.secureuri);
    var frameId = 'jUploadFrame' + id;
    var formId = 'jUploadForm' + id;        
    // Watch for a new set of requests
    if ( s.global && ! jQuery.active++ )
    {
        jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStart" );
    }            
    var requestDone = false;
    // Create the request object
    var xml = {}   
    if ( s.global )
        jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxSend", [xml, s]);
    // Wait for a response to come back
    var uploadCallback = function(isTimeout)
    {           
        var io = document.getElementById(frameId);
        try 
        {               
            if(io.contentWindow)
            {
                 xml.responseText = io.contentWindow.document.body?io.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML:null;
                 xml.responseXML = io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument?io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument:io.contentWindow.document;

            }else if(io.contentDocument)
            {
                 xml.responseText = io.contentDocument.document.body?io.contentDocument.document.body.innerHTML:null;
                xml.responseXML = io.contentDocument.document.XMLDocument?io.contentDocument.document.XMLDocument:io.contentDocument.document;
            }                       
        }catch(e)
        {
            jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e);
        }
        if ( xml || isTimeout == "timeout") 
        {               
            requestDone = true;
            var status;
            try {
                status = isTimeout != "timeout" ? "success" : "error";
                // Make sure that the request was successful or notmodified
                if ( status != "error" )
                {
                    // process the data (runs the xml through httpData regardless of callback)
                    var data = jQuery.uploadHttpData( xml, s.dataType );    
                    // If a local callback was specified, fire it and pass it the data
                    if ( s.success )
                        s.success( data, status );

                    // Fire the global callback
                    if( s.global )
                        jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxSuccess", [xml, s] );
                } else
                    jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status);
            } catch(e) 
            {
                status = "error";
                jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status, e);
            }

            // The request was completed
            if( s.global )
                jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxComplete", [xml, s] );

            // Handle the global AJAX counter
            if ( s.global && ! --jQuery.active )
                jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStop" );

            // Process result
            if ( s.complete )
                s.complete(xml, status);

            jQuery(io).unbind()

            setTimeout(function()
                                {   try 
                                    {
                                        jQuery(io).remove();
                                        jQuery(form).remove();  

                                    } catch(e) 
                                    {
                                        jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e);
                                    }                                   

                                }, 100)

            xml = null

        }
    }
    // Timeout checker
    if ( s.timeout > 0 ) 
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            // Check to see if the request is still happening
            if( !requestDone ) uploadCallback( "timeout" );
        }, s.timeout);
    }
    try 
    {

        var form = jQuery('#' + formId);
        jQuery(form).attr('action', s.url);
        jQuery(form).attr('method', 'POST');
        jQuery(form).attr('target', frameId);
        if(form.encoding)
        {
            jQuery(form).attr('encoding', 'multipart/form-data');               
        }
        else
        {   
            jQuery(form).attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');            
        }           
        jQuery(form).submit();

    } catch(e) 
    {           
        jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e);
    }

    jQuery('#' + frameId).load(uploadCallback   );
    return {abort: function () {}}; 

},

uploadHttpData: function( r, type ) {
    var data = !type;
    data = type == "xml" || data ? r.responseXML : r.responseText;
    // If the type is "script", eval it in global context
    if ( type == "script" )
        jQuery.globalEval( data );
    // Get the JavaScript object, if JSON is used.
    if ( type == "json" )
        eval( "data = " + data );
    // evaluate scripts within html
    if ( type == "html" )
        jQuery("<div>").html(data).evalScripts();

    return data;
}
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`handleError` was deprecated from jquery 1.5 and up. I switched from the plugin you are using to this one: http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/iframe-post-form.html

It's much simpler and it is pretty easy to modify the plugin to your specific form.

You could try to write your own `handleError` function as this post suggests: [When was handleError removed from jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329589/when-was-handleerror-removed-from-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of jQuery are you using? It seems that multiple plugins have problems like the one you're faced with. See, for example, [this thread](http://www.codemastersintl.com/Blogs/Andrey-Kuleshov/2011/2/8/first-look-at-jquery-15-).

In some cases, updating to latests version of both jQuery and the plugin would do the trick.

Either way, it that's not working, what happens when you embed a earlier version of jQuery, does it solves the problem? Cause that would mean the problem is not in your script, but inside the plugin itself.

Comment: In jQuery 1.2.1 works good, but in v1.5.1 it shows error. I use this http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/ plugin but as I see it's not in development anymore. Maybe you know similar plugin like this?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the answer of @jk; that could do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too when integrating ajaxFileUpload, I stumbled across my answer by logging  the error to console and googling it:

```
               //status = "error";
               // jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status, e);
               console.log(s);
               console.log(xml);
               console.log(status);
               console.log(e);
```

then when the error fired I found out that syntax in the call was wrong. it turns out dataType needs to be capitalized as JSON(credit goes to shwetanka here: [AjaxFileUpload SyntaxError: missing } in XML expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939741/ajaxfileupload-syntaxerror-missing-in-xml-expression))

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
                   dataType : 'JSON',
```

make sure the server is encoding the response back in json and you should be fine