# Sorting the strings inside the plugin

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, sorting

I have a javascript plugin here that I wrote for a website and I am working on modifying the plugin to add some additional functionality.

The plugin earlier accepted an array of items as the input as follows (to finally create a small visualization):

```
Tom Hank
Will Smith
Chirstopher Nolan
Keanu Reeves
```

Internally, the plugin used a sort function to sort the names as follows:

```
groups = groups.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.content > b.content) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (a.content < b.content) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
```

where `a.content` and `b.content` are all strings such as `"Keanu Reaves"` etc.

However, now I have changed the input being sent to the plugin and instead of sending the input `strings`, I now send html as input. For eg:

```
<div class="sampleDiv"><span class="">Keanu Reaves</span></div>
<div class="sampleDiv"><span class="">Christopher</span></div> etc.
```

where each item is formed by

```
var itemSrc= '<div class="sampleDiv"><span class="">' +
              'Keanu Reaves' + 
             '</span></div>';
```

I have to sort the items in the plugin similarly (in that sort function), but now that I am sending html (a.content now has the above html), I wanted to get some ideas from SO on how I could sort in the above function (Previous sort should also be retained, in case I later change the input to sending only strings).
Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Instead of modifying the script to take html, why don't you create function to extract the text from the html into an array and then pass that into the function that you already have. Or you could create the html after you sort the names.

Comment: @elclanrs : If I don't the pass the custom html as I doing now, I won't be able to provide a proper visualization for each item. However, what I can do is to provide the user to turn on an option `isCustomHtmlPassed: true` in which the extraction method could be inside the plugin itself. Would that be a correct approach?

Comment: If you can't sort before creating the html for whatever reason then I'd use the DOM with document fragments, then sort, then append to container.

Comment: Or should I also passed the extraction method as well since the html can be passed in n number of ways in which case it becomes the responsibility of the user to pass the extraction method as well.

Comment: @elclanrs : Can you provide a bit detail about what exactly would be DOM with document fragments approach?

Comment: Since it appears that each item would be wrapped in the same markup, why not just accept an array of strings as before and allow an option, e.g. `itemMarkupTemplate: '<div class="sampleDiv"><span class="">{{data}}</span></div>'`, that each item will be wrapped in after the sort? This can be a simple replace or some kind of super-lazy templating (transform it into a function), but you'd probably want to do some benchmarking if you go this way.

Comment: Actually, instead of having the user pass an extraction method, it might make more sene to have them pass as an option a function that will wrap each item: `formatItem: function(item){ return '<markup>'+item+'</markup>'; }`.

Comment: @user1240679 When you sort the items, try [to remove the html tags with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1499916/1401975).

Answer (score 1):

In your sort function, first strip the html tags. With the resulting string, then perform the sort.

```
    groups = groups.sort(function (a, b) {
        var x = a.toLowerCase().replace(/<[a-zA-Z\/][^>]*>/g,''), y = b.toLowerCase().replace(/<[a-zA-Z\/][^>]*>/g,'');
        return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
    });
```

I hope this helps.