# Full text based Search on Client Machine using Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom, full-text-search

I am trying to implement a full text-based search functionality on a client machine.

I've found that [Lunr.js](http://lunrjs.com/) satisfies my requirement partially, but it has to be loaded on a Server like Apache, then it works perfectly.

In my case, the client machine will not have any server or DB installed. There will just be a bunch of static HTML files in a directory, and one index file accepting the user's input from a search box, which searches for this string in those static HTML files.

Google search revealed some interesting words which (might) be needed in my project: `innerHtml`, `DOM`, `iframes` and `RegExp`.

Please formulate my queries to your answers. Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to search *in files*?  Pretty sure you can't client-side.

Comment: Searching in files client-sise would be overkill. You will have to **transfer all files to client using javascript which is totally bad idea**. Every page given limited amount of resources, as well some peoples using low-speed connections. That would be usable **only if you have small amount of text**.

Comment: @Sanya_Zol No transferring of files. All HTML files are present on Client's local machine. Just a search of all those HTML files is needed when user searches for a Word...

Comment: @highlander141 you can't do that (because local page security context is only one page), st least directly. But you can: Use [XML index as Milind Anantwar suggested](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/simple-javascriptxml-based) (but this requires embedding/converting all the data into one file) or using search software (which can be [html application and done in JavaScript](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Simple-file-search-hta-m45254.aspx) (note the **hta** file extension) as well as [software like google desktop](http://www.gtricks.com/google-tricks/google-desktop-search-alternatives/)

Comment: @Sanya_Zol +1 for mentioning HTML Applications. Can this search like a string/ phrase inside a file??

Comment: Are there still outstanding issues for this question?

Answer (score 2):

There is one way I could think of doing this - you could fetch the local files using XMLHttpRequest. This is not allowed by default, but for example chromium can be started with the following parameter:

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

You would have to go through all the files you want to look at and implement the search manually by [stripping html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499889/remove-html-tags-in-javascript-with-regex) and performing regex, that shouldn't be hard.

I tested the following code in chromium:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "file:///your-file.html";

xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
xmlhttp.onerror = function(e) { console.log('Problems' + e); };

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 0) {
        console.log("Fetched: ");
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);

    }
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        // ....
    }
    else if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status != 200) {
        // ....
    }
}

xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Altough I haven't tried to using it in this way, you could have a look at [jIO](http://www.j-io.org/) ([Github](https://github.com/nexedi/jio))

jIO can be used to manage and sync JSON documents across multiple storages (browser localstorage, webDav, xWiki, S3...). Storages can be indexed and jIO comes with it's own query module, called complexQueries, that can also be used standalone.

If you request pages via Ajax and extract the full text/HTML of your page, just dump it into jIO as a document.

**Three ways to do (all examples from the [jIO documentation](http://www.j-io.org/documentation)):**

**1) Use plain localstorage and complex queries**
Create a document in jIO for every document you want to have searchable. So after setting up your jIO:

```
var mySearchFiles = JIO.newJio({
    "type" : "local",
    "username" : "whatever",
    "application_name" : "fulltextsearch"
 });
```

add the full HTML/extracted text (localstorage size limit...) as a document like so:

```
mySearchFiles.put({
    "_id": "your_id",
    "search_result_string": "page_title/page_filename",
    "searchable_text": "your_text_to_be_searched_goes_here",
    function (err, response) {
        // console.log(response) =
        // {
        //  "ok": true,
        //  "id": "your_id",
        // }
    }
```

);

Either use the `_id` or another custom key as what you want to have returned from jIO when searching.

Then run complex queries on your jIO using the allDocs method ([here](https://github.com/nexedi/jio/blob/master/examples/example-queries.html) is an example page to play around with complex queries):

```
// here you construct your basic query
var query_object = {
    "query":{
        "filter": {
            // records from/to to be returned
            "limit":[0,10],
            // sort direction
            "sort_on":[[search_result_string, "ascending"]],
            // what fields to return
            "select_list":[["search_result_string"]]
        },
        // wildchard
        "wildcard_character":'%'
    }
};

// build your query - if user entered the variable "search_term":
var search = "searchable_text: = %" + search_term + "%"; 

// add to query object
query_object.query.query = search;

// run the search
mySearchFiles.allDocs(
   query_object,
   function (err, response){
      console.log(response);
   }
);
```

This should return the `search_result_string` you want. I don't know how fast it will be on large texts to search, but you could write your own search grammar, if you want, using [JSCC Parser Generator](http://jscc.phorward-software.com/).

**2. Use only complex queries**
You can use the `parse`, `serialize` and `query` methods used in ComplexQueries standalone. Check out the examples page [link as above](https://github.com/nexedi/jio/blob/master/examples/example-queries.html) on how it works.

Basically you need to have the data you want searched available as an object list and your query must be serialized. Then just call:

```
var result = jIO.ComplexQueries.query(query, object_list);
```

Of course, you would need some place to keep your searchable data, so I would probably go with localStorage alongside.

**3. Add an indexStorage on top of localStorage**
You can add an index on top of localStorage like so:

```
 mySearchFiles = JIO.newJio({
    "type": "indexed",
    "indices": [
        {"name":"index_name", "fields":["field_to_be_indexed_1"]},
        {"name":"index_name2", "fields":["field_to_be_indexed_1","field_to_be_indexed_2"]}
    ],
    "field_types": {
      "field_to_be_indexed_1": "string",
      "field_to_be_indexed_2": "string"
    },
    "sub_storage": {
      "type": "local",
      "username": "whatever",
      "application_name": "fulltextsearch"
    }
});
```

This will create an index for all documents you add to your localstorage, which would allow you to do a keyword search on the files before digging through all files using complexQueries for example. So:

```
mySearchFiles.put({
    "_id": "your_id",
    "search_result_string": "page_title/page_filename",
    "index_field": "keyword",
    "index_field2": "another_keyword",
    "searchable_text": "your_text_to_be_searched_goes_here",
    function (err, response) {
        // console.log(response) =
        // {
        //  "ok": true,
        //  "id": "your_id",
        // }
    }
  );
```

You can call the same methods, but JIO will always try to query the index first to build the results. Actually this is more for remote storage locations (search the index before HTTP-requesting files from say ... S3), but nevertheless, maybe usable.

Let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your html files are static, if this is the case you could actually also have a json file with the text in each of your html files.

For example, lets sat you have two html pages, foo.html and bar.html, you could then extract the relevant content from each of these and create a json file containing the following:

```
[{
    "id": "foo.html",
    "text": "whatever text is in foo.html"
},{
    "id": "bar.html",
    "text": "whatever text is in bar.html"
}]
```

This would live in the directory with your html in, e.g

```
- project_dir
-- foo.html
-- bar.html
-- index.json
```

Then you can use the index file with lunr.js.

How you go about actually building the index.json file depends on what tools you have available, although something like [boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) or readability.  There are more options discussed here http://readwrite.com/2011/03/19/text-extraction