# How to select specific text between HTML tags with RegExp?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, conditional-statements

I am building an application which needs to select specific text between html, here is an example:

String:
`<p><a href="test0">test1 test2</a>test3</p>`

RegExp: `(Select text between HTML)(test.)`

What I want to select is "test1","test2" and "test3" but not "test0"

Is there any solution??Thanks for any helps

Note: I am using JavaScript for RegExp operation.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: @Shekhar, this is not a duplicate, the OP wants a JavaScript solution, your link is C# related

Comment: @Shekhar : This question is different from the one you mentioned.

Comment: @chunheisiu your question is unclear, do you want to select the text from this specific html fragment or do you want a more generic solution?

Comment: Ok @ValentinVasilyev here is a similar link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499889/remove-html-tags-in-javascript-with-regex

Comment: [Looks like you are trying to parse HTML with Regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage on the browser's ability to parse HTML for you:

```
var html = '<p><a href="test0">test1 test2</a>test3</p>',
fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
div = fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

div.innerHTML = html;

console.log(div.textContent || div.innerText || '');
```

Outputs:

```
test1 test2test3
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use Regexes for this kind of task, if all you need is text of `<p>` tag, I'd use 
jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p><a href="test0">test1 test2</a>test3</p>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    text = $('p').text();
    alert(text);
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This returns `test1 test2test3`

Working example: http://jsbin.com/uhadoz/1/

If you'd like a more generic solution, you still can use jquery, just change the selector:
for example, to get the text of all `divs`, use `$('div').text()`

But if you have  serious parsing needs, you'd better use an HTML parser, google for 
JavaScript HTML parser, for example this one: http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/

Read this SO question about parsing HTML with Regexes: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I think OP requires a more generic solution, i.e. not restricted to just `<p>` tags but ALL tags which can have text contents.