# Javascript .replace() not working

Tags: javascript, replace

```
carList = cars.innerHTML;
alert(carList);
carList = carList.replace("<center>","").replace("</center>","").replace("<b>","").replace("</b>","");
alert(carList);
```

[image]

Why in the world is this happening? I've tried splitting this out into individual string.replace()'s and that gives the same result.

Comment: replace one instance versus replace all.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: or you could remove all HTML tags (which I think is what you want) => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499889/remove-html-tags-in-javascript-with-regex

Comment: A basic example works here: http://jsfiddle.net/MQNGJ/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using `.replace()` with a string will only fix the first occurrence which is what you are seeing. If you do it with a regular expression instead you can specify that it should be global (by specifying it with a `g` afterwards) and thus take all occurrences.

```
carList = "<center>blabla</center> <b>some bold stuff</b> <b>some other bold stuff</b>";
alert(carList);
carList = carList.replace(/<center>/g,"").replace(/<\/center>/g,"").replace(/<b>/g,"").replace(/<\/b>/g,"");
alert(carList);
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XEAY7/) for a working sample.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to match all of these at the same time:

```
carList = carList.replace(/<\/?(b|center)>/g,"");
```

The `g` flag at the end of the match string tells Javascript to replace all occurrences, not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the space completely from a string value. you ca use

```
/g
```

```js
var str="javasript is amazing when you crack it";
alert(str.replace(/ /g,"+"));
```