# jQuery: parse HTML into text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use `substr()` on a string to output a set of characters from a message. My problem is that if the string contains HTML I would get the tags in the text.

Is it possible to parse the HTML before using `substr()` to only extract the text from the message itself?

### Example 1:

```
var string = "Hi";

alert(string.substr(0, 7));
```

Alert:

> `Hi`

### Example 2:

```
var string = "<br/>Hi";

alert(string.substr(0, 7));
```

Alert:

> `<br/>Hi`

Comment: How does `string` get populated? You could do something like `$(string).text()`, but there's probably a much more efficient way that doesn't involve `jQuery`.

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `jQuery.text()` method, you can extract only the text.

```
var str = "<br/>Hi"

$('<p>' + str + '</p>').text(); //Wrap your input in a p element first to ensure you get the text if your string isn't wrapped in HTML.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the html via a regex, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499889/remove-html-tags-in-javascript-with-regex) and you can do something like this:

```
String.prototype.removeHtml=function(){
  return this.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
}

var string = "<br/>Hi";

alert(string.removeHtml().substr(0, 7));
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fx3MJ/

[Remove HTML Tags in Javascript with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499889/remove-html-tags-in-javascript-with-regex)

Answer (score 2):

Yes using this:

```
var string = "<br/>Hi";
var stringStripped = string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
alert(stringStripped);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hutchonoid/7T56N/

Answer (score 1):

If you input is read in the DOM, you can use jQuery to get just the text. Example :

```
<p id="foo"><br />Hi</p>

var string = $('#foo').text();

alert(string.substr(0, 7)); //says "Hi"
```

See jQuery doc for [reference](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Edit:
If your input comes from somewhere else, you can still use jQuery, but there may be better solution.

```
var input = "<br />Hi";
var fakeElement = $('<div>' + input + '</div>');

var string = fakeElement.text();

alert(string.substr(0, 7)); //says "Hi"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace html-tag with regex pattern

```
var string = string.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the text with HTML tag, try to use .innerHTML from jQuery.

```
<p id="foo"><br />Hi</p>
```

```
$("#foo")[0].innerHTML;
```

Console: `"<br />Hi"`

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage jQuery's `text()` function:

```
 $('<div>').append('<br />hi').text();
```

This creates a new element, to which you can append your markup, and then use `text()` to extract the text. A little round-about, but it works.

I'd recommend a regex solution over this.

Comment: Using `jQuery.append()` [**here is wildly inefficient compared to string concatenation**](http://jsperf.com/js-concat-vs-jquery-append).

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to tuck that away!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var string = "<br/Hi>".replace(/&#39;/g, '\'').replace(/&amp;/g, '&').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&apos;/g, '\'');
alert(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var string = "<br/>Hi";

alert($('<span>'+string+'</span>').text().substr(0, 7));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/B8Sr9/)