# To Stop a user to comment html content

Tags: javascript

How can i stop a user from typing html content in text-area in JavaScript? means A user would not able to comment html content. 
 Any help would be highly appriciated.

Comment: Strip the tags when they submit? Are you submitting it to a database? What server side script do you use?

Comment: yea i am submitting to database. and what does tags strip means ? actually i am new in this . and i am using php as a server side language

Comment: In that case you can do `strip_tags($_POST['textarea']);`

Comment: can we do this in JavaScript? because i want user should  not be able to enter tags

Comment: You want them to be able to enter tags but not HTML? I'm confused.

Comment: i want them not able enter tags

Comment: as he enters tags there should be an alert of any type.

Comment: Actually I dont understand what this mean `To Stop a user to comment html content`.  But I can guess you're trying something like in this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1499889/1671639

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) to get rid of any tags a user tries to submit via your textarea.
You can just do the following:

```
$comment = strip_tags($_POST['comment']);
```

As a second (optional) parameter, you can add tags you want to allow.