# How do I allow <img> and <a> tags for innerHTML, but no others? (Making a forum)

Tags: javascript, php, innerhtml

I am currently programming a forum using only javascript (No JQuery please). I am doing very well, however, there is one issue I would love help with.

Currently I am getting the post from a database, assigning it to variable MainPost, and then attaching it to a div via a text node:

```
     var theDiv = document.getElementById("MainBody");
     var content = document.createTextNode(MainPost);
     theDiv.appendChild(content);
```

This is working quite well, however, I would LOVE to be able to do this:

```
     document.getElementById("MainBody").innerHTML += MainPost;
```

But I know this would allow people to use ANY html tag they want, even something like "script" followed by javascript code. This would be bad for business, obviously, but I do like the idea of allowing posters to use the "img" tag as well as the "a href" tags. Is there a way to somehow disable all tags except these two for the innerHTML?

Thank you all so much for any help you can offer.

Comment: I recommend to use BBCode processing (search in Google to use it ).

Comment: Filter the data on the server side, before storing in database and/or after retrieving it from database. If you are using PHP, you can use DOMDocument.

Comment: I just did some PHP research and found the strip_tags() function. It seems to do exactly what I want, with the 2nd parameter being exceptions for img and a. Sound good? I'll be trying it tomorrow.

Comment: A more versatile option is to use XML functions such as `DOMDocument`. It, for example, allows you to handle the `<a href>` case where you can remove all attributes from `<a>` except href.

Comment: @SalmanA do you have any relevant example or jsfiddle you can point to to help me with this php DOMDocument stuff? I have not heard of it before, but it looks like the right idea.

Comment: @Joshua231 cannot use to show PHP code; try [searching on SO for DOMDocument help](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+nodes+using+domdocument)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the first thought that came to my mind when I read this question was to find a regular expression to exclude a specific string in a word. Simple search gave [a lot of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717644/regular-expression-that-doesnt-contain-certain-string) [from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395177/regex-to-exclude-a-specific-string-constant).

Starting point - To remove all the HTML tags from a string ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499889/remove-html-tags-in-javascript-with-regex)):

```
 var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
 ,   body = "<p>test</p>"
 ,   result = body.replace(regex, "");

 console.log(result);
```

To exclude a string you would do something like this (again from all the source mentioned above):

```
(?!StringToBeExcluded)
```

Since you want to exlcude the `<a href` and `<img` tags. The suitable regex in your case could be:

```
(<(?![\/]?a)(?![\/]?img)([^>]+)>)
```

**Explanation :**

Think of it as three capturing groups in succession:

1. `(?![\/]?a)` : Negative Lookahead to assert that it is impossible to match the regex containing the string "a" prefixed by zero or one backslashes (Should take care of the `a href` tags)
2. `(?![\/]?img)` : Same as 1, just here it looks for the string "img". I don't know why I allowed the  `</img>` tag. Yes, `<img>` doesn't have a closing tag. You could remove the `[\/]?` bit from it to fix this.
3. `([^>]+)` : Makes sure to not match `>` zero or one times to take care of tags that have opening and closing tags.

Now all these capture groups lie between `<` and `>`. You might want to try [a regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dY7uW7/2) that I've created incorporating these three capture groups to take care of ignoring all `HTML` elements except the image and link tags.

*Sidenote* - I haven't thoroughly given this regex a try. Feel free to play around with it and tweak it according to your needs. In any case, I hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: @Joshua231, please mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you so that others in a similar situation would also benefit out of it. Thanks.

Comment: I believe [this](https://regex101.com/r/XcMioY/1) would be more complete because yours only matches tags that **start with** `a`, which means anyone could add an `audio` tag or an `abbr` tag or something else that starts with `a`.  The one I have sent only matches tags that *are* `a` tags.  I hope this helps anyone that noticed this problem!