# Search without Accents Using Datatable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using the Datatable plugin to be able to search the tables. Also, to be able to search for words that contain accents without having to indicate the accents I added the following code that removes all the accents to the words:

```
 jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string = function ( data ) {

return ! data ?
    '' :
    typeof data === 'string' ?
        data
            .replace( /\n/g, ' ' )
            .replace( /[áâàä]/g, 'a' )
            .replace( /[éêèë]/g, 'e' )
            .replace( /[íîìï]/g, 'i' )
            .replace( /[óôòö]/g, 'o' )
            .replace( /[úûùü]/g, 'u' )
            .replace( /ç/g, 'c' ) :
        data;
};
```

This works correctly for any search in the table. But now I need to be able to do the same in another table whose cells contents are a list or a button, since I need to be able to drag the table element to another list using sortable jquery-ui.

That is, I have the following structure:

```
<table class="scrollTable dataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="info">
 <thead class="fixedHeader">
  ...
 </thead>
 <tbody class="scrollContent">
   <tr role="row">
     <td class="sorting_1">
       <button >Peter</button>
     </td>
   </tr>
  ...
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Or

```
<table class="scrollTable dataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="info">
 <thead class="fixedHeader">
  ...
 </thead>
 <tbody class="scrollContent">
   <tr role="row">
     <td class="sorting_1">
       <ul>
       <li>Peter</li>
       </ul>
     </td>
   </tr>
  ...
 </tbody>
</table>
```

And I need to be able to transform the words with accents and using the code I indicated above but adding some reference to those lists or buttons in `jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string =...`

Since it only refers to the text of a cell and not to a button or list.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will search columns for accented characters using the non-accented equivalent. It also supports searching the inner text of html content.

It works by setting up new a column type to support searching the text of the html, as well as 'normalising' any accented characters it may have. I have called this new column type `html-string`. You only need apply this particular column type to columns that contain html. Other columns will automatically have their accents 'normalised' during search:

```
// set up a custom column type to strip html tags and normalise the characters for searching
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html-string'] = function(sData) {

  // strip html tags (you will need to test this regex for your needs. Source from http://stackoverflow.com/a/25885923/1544886)
  sData = sData.replace(/(&nbsp;|<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");

  // apply character normaliser to this column type
  return jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string(sData);
}

jQuery.fn.DataTable.ext.type.search.string = function(data) {

  return !data ?
    '' :
    typeof data === 'string' ?
    data
    .replace(/έ/g, 'ε')
    .replace(/[ύϋΰ]/g, 'υ')
    .replace(/ό/g, 'ο')
    .replace(/ώ/g, 'ω')
    .replace(/ά/g, 'α')
    .replace(/[ίϊΐ]/g, 'ι')
    .replace(/ή/g, 'η')
    .replace(/\n/g, ' ')
    .replace(/á/g, 'a')
    .replace(/é/g, 'e')
    .replace(/í/g, 'i')
    .replace(/ó/g, 'o')
    .replace(/ú/g, 'u')
    .replace(/ê/g, 'e')
    .replace(/î/g, 'i')
    .replace(/ô/g, 'o')
    .replace(/è/g, 'e')
    .replace(/ï/g, 'i')
    .replace(/ü/g, 'u')
    .replace(/ã/g, 'a')
    .replace(/õ/g, 'o')
    .replace(/ç/g, 'c')
    .replace(/ì/g, 'i') :
    data;
};
```

Then apply the new type to the appropriate columns:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "columnDefs": [{
     "type": "html-string",
     "targets": [2]
  }]
});
```

As noted in the code, you should test the html-stripping regex I chose. It worked for my example.

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/4gdea71p/2/

Comment: Thank you very much @KScandrett, it works. But I have a doubt, this is to look for words with accents but without inserting accents, but if I want both, what should I do? Because in this case if I enter the word with accents does not recognize it.

Comment: Use the code from the example at bottom of this page - https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/type-based/accent-neutralise

Comment: Thank you so much, I saw it before but I thought it was the same. I have already solved.