# How to remove HTML tags from rendered text

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, strip

I am needing to remove the opening and closing `<p>` tags from some rendered comment text. I pass the content to a component as a prop and i think that in doing so, it doesn't allow for the v-html directive to work correctly.

I need the content to render without the html tags

Here is where I am trying to render normally with v-html

```
 <textarea class="form-control comment-inline-edit" v-html="content" name="comment-inline-edit" cols="45" rows="3"></textarea>
```

And here is where I am passing the rendered content from the parent component

```
<CommentEdit v-show="isEditting" :content="comment.content.rendered" v-on:cancel="cancelEdit" />
```

Is there a VueJS way to do this other than using v-html?

Answer (score 30):

I would recommend you strip HTML from rendered text in VueJS using a **filter**, that way you can repeatedly use the filter around the application, rather than a specific singular computation.

I wrote the following, which utilizes the browser's parsing (most reliable method) as regex can be thwarted by user silliness:

```
Vue.filter('stripHTML', function (value) {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = value
  return text = div.textContent || div.innerText || '';
});
```

Once you include this in your `app.js` you can then render it anywhere as follows:

```
{{ pdf.description | stripHTML }}
```

Comment: Thanks @Grant .This worked well but what if i want to keep image tags, How would i go

Comment: Good answer but just note for other users... this is exactly usable for what it says is `striphtml` - so it is not XSS safe. It is vulnerable for e.g. input string containing `<img src='' onerror=alert('XSS')>`.

Answer (score 12):

```
  <p> @{{data.description | strippedContent}} </p>


filters: {
    strippedContent: function(string) {
           return string.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/ig, " "); 
    }
}
```

Working for me

Answer (score 8):

The question of how to remove HTML tags from text in javascript [already has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499889/remove-html-tags-in-javascript-with-regex).

The Vue way to do this would be to create a computed property that runs code to remove HTML tags from the rendered content and pass that to your `CommentEdit` component instead:

```
computed: {
  strippedContent() {
    let regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    return this.comment.content.rendered.replace(regex, "");
  }
}
```

```
<CommentEdit v-show="isEditting" :content="strippedContent" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @JonathonHibbard yeah, I don't know the very best way to strip out html tags. My example code came from googling "strip html tags javascript". I'm sure the asker can find something that will work for him. I'm telling him how to use a feature of Vue to run the stripping method and pass that data to his component.

Answer (score 0):

I was alarmed by @mikep's comment to @Grant's answer about XSS vulnerability. This would be a show stopper for me.

A quick test confirms it to be true:

```
        {{foo| stripHTML}}
...

  data:function(){return {
    foo: "<p><img src='' onerror=alert('XSS')/>some text</p>",
  }},
```

This shows the alert, proving the Javascript was injected and executed.

I found a technique to parse the HTML without attaching it to the DOM [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543346/209288) which is not vulnerable to the image attack.

I came up with this version of Grant's filter which simply renders the same test to `"some text"` with no alert shown.

```
Vue.filter('stripHTML', function (value) {
    let text = ''
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const dom = parser.parseFromString(value, "text/html");
    let div = dom.querySelector('body>*');
    if(div){
        text = div.textContent || div.innerText || ''
    }
    return text
});
```

Note this assumes there's a single top-level node in the content, like `<p>some stuff<p>`, but you could extend the query selector to handle other cases.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const re = /<[^<>]+>/g

:content="comment.content.replace(re, '')"
```

Hi, you could try this out!