# document.createElement without loading in DOM

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jquery-selectors, createelement

Is there a way to create a parsable Dom without running the code? I'll explain future;

I receive a whole bunch of CK-editor created code as a HTML, but want to parse elements from this to create a specified view. For example I'll like to grasp the first paragraph as an Intro and the first Image as a primary image. I'n addition I want to retrieve all images to create a gallery.

For doing this I've created a simple, but effective function:

```
export const getFromContent = (html, qsa) => {
    const elm = document.createElement("DIV");
    elm.innerHTML = html;
    let r = elm.querySelectorAll(qsa);
    return r;
}
```

This work almost perfect- the only issue is that is adds everything to the DOM (do I use the term correctly?), which means that all resources gets loaded even if it does not show on the Page.

In my example I would like to load all images through //res.cloudinary.com/ com compress images before shown, but since all images already is loaded, this wont be necessary.

Is there a way to get to keep the good "version" of this with just basic JS?

PS: I know that I could rewrite all "src" to "presrc" with a REGEX, but I would really like to do this without changing the code, and thereby create space for errors.

Best regards
Richard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This work almost perfect- the only issue is that is adds everything to the DOM...

It creates DOM elements (that's why you're doing it!), but it **doesn't** add them to the window's document. **Beware** doing that can run code that's in the HTML, though (details below). Doing that:

- **Won't** put the `div` or its contents anywhere in the document.
- **Won't** load any stylesheets defined by `link` tags in the HTML.
- **Won't** fetch any script files referenced by `script src="xyz"` tags in the HTML (and thus won't run the code).
- **Won't** run any code in inline `script` tags in the HTML.
- ***Will*** add event handlers defined via `onXyz` attributes on elements in the HTML.
- ***Will*** load any images defined in the HTML.

It's the combination of those last two points that means it can run arbitrary code, like this:

```js
const getFromContent = (html, qsa) => {
    const elm = document.createElement("DIV");
    elm.innerHTML = html;
    let r = elm.querySelectorAll(qsa);
    return r;
};

getFromContent(
    `<img
        src="http://example.com/alksdjflsadkf"
        onload="console.log('Arbitrary code ran!');"
        onerror="console.log('Arbitrary code ran!');"
    >`,
    "p"
);
```

If you later add that `div` to the document, that will load any stylesheets defined by `link` tags in the HTML but **won't** run code in `script` elements (either inline or referenced via `src`).

That said, you might want to look at using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead.

```
export const getFromContent = (html, selector) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const dom = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    let r = dom.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return r;
};
```

It won't even load images defined in the HTML, and although it adds handlers defined via inline `onXyz` attributes, it doesn't fire any events, so those handlers won't be run — until or unless you add the resulting document's contents to an active document. It **just** parses the tree and returns a document.

Live Example:

```js
const getFromContent = (html, selector) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const dom = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    let r = dom.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return r;
};

const content = `
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>
        Paragraph 2
        <img
            src="http://example.com/alksdjflsadkf"
            onload="console.log('Arbitrary code ran!');"
            onerror="console.log('Arbitrary code ran!');"
        >
    </p>
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
`;
const paragraphs = getFromContent(content, "p");
console.log(paragraphs.length);
for (const paragraph of paragraphs) {
    console.log(paragraph.textContent);
}
```

Note that the `img`'s inline handlers were never fired. They *would* be if you added the `img` elements (or their ancestors) to an active document:

---

**Note:** When accepting user input and rendering it as HTML, it's often important to **sanitize** that input before using it, to remove unwanted content. For instance, I mentioned that `script` elements wouldn't be evaluated, and that's true, but if the content had `<img src="javascript:doSomethingNefarious()">` in it, and you appended that image to a document (directly or indirectly), that `doSomethingNefarious()` code would be executed. Similarly, `<div onclick="doSomethingNefarious()">x</div>`.

If you search for "HTML sanitizer" you'll find a lot of different libraries out there that say they'll do it for you. The problem is significant enough, though, that a means of doing it is in the process of being standardized as the [Sanitization API](https://github.com/WICG/sanitizer-api). Early days yet, but it's a very promising development. With the API in its current (very draft) form, you could do:

```
export const getFromContent = (html, selector) => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setHTML(html);  // <== `setHTML` is a new method that sanitizes.
                        // Here I'm using the default sanitizer, but you
                        // could create one with your own custom settings
                        // and pass it as the second argument
    let r = div.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return r;
};
```

But the API is still in flux.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for, I also got a trip down the memorylane, since I obviously had this problem earlier. Thank you for great information.