# Just remove outermost tag in javascript using regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I have the string:

```
<template>
    <view class="container">{{title}}</view>
</template>
```

or

```
<custom>
    anything...
</cusomt>
```

I just want to remove `template`/`custom` tag and keep the tags inside `template`/`custom`.

The method in [Remove HTML Tags in Javascript with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499889/remove-html-tags-in-javascript-with-regex) will remove all tags.

#### Note: I'm not developing a web page. I just use `node` to process string.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html.

Comment: I just want using regex extract the content inside tag. Just remove the string of outermost tag.

Comment: In general regex is not meant to match patterns with matching closing and opening sequences (like tags or quotes). Some extensions to standard regex can allow for this but often result in clunky and complicated regexes. You will be much better off using the built-in DOM parser.

Comment: Don't use a regular expression to parse HTML, see [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Okay, I got it. So, there's other solution in `node`?

Comment: @tomfriwel—use a DOM parser, modify the DOM as required, then maybe serialise it so you get the HTML back (it might not be identical markup but should be equivalent). See answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Javascript, why not use something like `document.getElementsByTagName('template')` and then extract the children?

```
var templateElements = document.getElementsByTagName('template');
var processedElements = [];

for (var i = 0; i < templateElements.length; i++) {
    var templateParent = templateElements[i];
    var children = templateParent.children;
    processedElements.push(children);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is not very clear. I'm using `node`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DOM Parser` API as regex aren't supposed to parse XML or HTML,

```js
let s = `<template>
    <view class="container">{{title}}</view>
</template>`;
let s1 = `<custom>
    anything...
</custom>`;
let d = new DOMParser();
let doc = d.parseFromString(s, 'application/xml');
let doc1 = d.parseFromString(s1, 'application/xml');
let r = doc.children[0].innerHTML;
console.log(r);
let r1 = doc1.children[0].innerHTML;
console.log(r1)
```

**Edit**

As you are in a node environment but I would still recommend you to use a DOM parsing library.

You could also use `/\<.*\>([\s\S]*)\<\/.*\>/`. This regex doesn't check for validity but assumes the provided markup is valid.

**Demo**

```js
let s = `<template>
<view class="container">{{title}}</view>
</template>`;
let s1 = `<custom>
    anything...
</custom>`;
let re = /\<.*\>([\s\S]*)\<\/.*\>/
console.log(re.exec(s)[1].trim());
console.log(re.exec(s1)[1].trim());
```

**Edit2**

You can also use `cheerio` like below :-

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
let s = `<template>
<view class="container">{{title}}</view>
</template>`;
let $ = cheerio.load('<div id="myid">' + s + '</div>');
console.log($('#myid>:nth-child(1)').html().trim());
```

Comment: Is there a proper DOM parser in `node`? I looked for it, but I couldn't find the proper library to do it.

Comment: Maybe `htmlparser2`. `cheerio` is based upon this.

Comment: @tomfriwel Also you can do this with `cheerio` as I have edited